# Semantic-ui integration with Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, semantic-ui

Semantic-ui is integrated with my laravel app. All buttons are working but **Menubar** is not working i.e whatever code I copied from documentation it is showing like that only.

I have linked these files -

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('semantic/dist/semantic.min.css')}}">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('semantic/dist/semantic.min.js')}}"></script>

    <div class="ui secondary  menu"> 
       <a class="active item"> Home </a>
       <a class="item"> Messages </a>
       <a class="item"> Friends </a>
    <div class="right menu">
      <div class="item">
        <div class="ui icon input">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
          <i class="search link icon"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="ui item"> Logout </a>
    </div>
```

By default Home is active but when i click or focus on another item i.e messages or Friends , it is not showing as active otherwise hovering effect is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

As you see, only the first menu item is marked as `active` in your code, so why do you expect any other menu items to be marked as `active` when you click on them?

```
<a class="active item"> Home </a>
```

You should detect which menu item is active when you render the menu and set `active` class to the necessary item.

So, for example, when you are on "Home" page your menu should look like this:

```
   <a class="active item"> Home </a>
   <a class="item"> Messages </a>
   <a class="item"> Friends </a>
```

But when your are on the "Friends" page your menu should look like this instead:

```
   <a class="item"> Home </a>
   <a class="item"> Messages </a>
   <a class="active item"> Friends </a>
```

And everything else depends on your implementation (either it's PHP or other server-side language if you generate your menu or JavaScript if you toggle its state in the browser).

Comment: Because in documentation it's working i.e whichever item is clicked that is marked as active.

Comment: Show me this documentation if possible

Comment: I have copied code for menu from here - https://semantic-ui.com/collections/menu.html#secondary-menu , and here after clicking or focusing it's changing the active menu item

Comment: I followed this given procedure to integrate semantic-ui with laravel - https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/elixir/semantic-ui-integration , I did this steps and semantic-ui buttons and all other components are working fine as well as menu is also displaying but only activeness of item is not working. please guide me how to solve this issue.

Comment: "Source code" there gives you only a current state of menu (if you select anything else there you'd get different code). So it's not a *real* working implementation, but just an example. As I have said in my answer, you must set active items on your own based on which page you are currently.

Comment: Okay, so i have to do this by own right? I was thinking that there may be problem with integration of semantic ui with laravel i.e semantic.min.js is not working.